# Картинка как фон панели в Swing

Tags: java, swing

Возможно ли сделать картинку фоном панели на подоби иконки?

```js
f = ImageIO.read(StartFrame.class.getResourceAsStream("f.gif"));
setIconImage(new ImageIcon(f).getImage());
```

Comment: проще задать `JLabel` layout и использовать вместо `JPanel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не то чтобы проще, но лично мне понятнее было: можно добавить на JFrame, 
JLayeredPane. Это те же 4 строчки, но управление чуть удобнее.

```
JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        setLayeredPane(layeredPane);
        layeredPane.add( myPanel, new Integer(0) );
        layeredPane.add( myButton, new Integer(1) );
```

у меня кнопка на фоне панели.
Но тут есть один нюанс, размеры фрейма задавать придется вручную, отталкиваясь скорее всего от "фона", т.е. размеров вашей картинки. Кроме того, выравнивание и размеры компонентов тоже задаем вручную, я делала через .setBounds.

Answer (score 3):

Придётся отнаследоваться от JPanel и переопределить метод `paintComponent`:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Здесь bgImage - ваша картинка.

Comment: Этот способ понятен. А по проще нет? Что бы как иконку в две строчки?

Comment: @AlexSMiheev нет, встроенного способа нет. Здесь и так короткий код, если для вас это важно.